# Samsung DEX in Bulgarian Phonetic

Tags: samsung, keyboard, samsung-dex

I am trying to type from my computer on the connected Samsung Cell Phone (in Viber) in Bulgarian.
There is Bulgarian Phonetic both on the phone and the computer.
The Bulgarian that comes up when typing is not Phonetic but BDS.
Is there a way to use Phonetic (maybe with Russian) while typing with a connection DEX ?